# PHP Force remote image download or remote requests inside an email

Tags: php, email, newsletter

I am sending our HTML newsletters with an image on each email that help us know if a person actually received that newsletter.

I just add in the HTML body of the email a img tag like that:

```
<img src="https://www.example.com/read/BASE64URLENCODED_DATA" />
```

BASE64URLENCODED_DATA is something that I can read on server when the request arrives to know the email address that downloaded that image. We receive the request to download that fake image, we save the data and return some headers to show a transparent image of 1x1 px.

The problem is that usually this works for no more than the 10% of the total emails sent on each newsletter. This means that most of the email clients that receive our newsletter don't permit the downloading of images (showing the classic message "If you want to download attached images click here...").

Is there any way to force an email client to make a remote request like that?

We need to produce more realistic statistics for our newsletters but we can't find a way to force this remote requests or fake images download.

Thank you.

Comment: Guess what, this is just why they have implemented the feature of not loading images by default.

Comment: It's not possible just to avoid such tricks :)

Comment: @naivists: I know. That's the why I asked this question ;)

Comment: You can add big text "If you want to full detail of message containing useful information allow us to show images" :P

Comment: @Robert: you sure? There is no way AT ALL? :(

Comment: @Robert: LOL I'll try to ask that to my customers :)

Comment: Even if I knew of a way, I wouldn't tell you. What else can we help you with? Stalking someone? Tax evasion?

Comment: You can only measure the trend relative to the last newsletters. You'll never get the exact opening rate which is around 40% higher.

Comment: @nl-x: if I ever would have stoke someone, I would just send him an email with acknowledgment request :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A longer answer - there may be ways how you can trick some e-mail clients, but this will work only on a particular client. There are lots of different clients out there. Maybe you find a way of tricking Oultook, but no guarantee that it works for Google Mail or other web mail service. Then there is Roundcube, Squirrelmail, Horde and other web clients. Then the mobile devices come in - iPhone/iPad mail client, Android mail clients, Outlook mobile.. No, you don't want to do this.

And even if you find a way of tricking all those programs (which I highly doubt), most likely your message will be malformatted and most spam filters will catch it as spam.

Comment: I'd guess that they measure the ratio between the e-mails sent and the customers actually visiting the promoted site.

Comment: Thank for your answer. You solved my doubts. I mean, I knew there were no ways to track newsletter emails, but I was wondering how email marketing services tried to build statistics on newsletters.